# Problem with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a problem with NSMutableArray.
In my program i have a lot of variabile "CFSocketRef".
i want to save this in NSMutableArray but i can't.
Can you help me?
Thank and sorry for my english XP

My code:

```
CFSocketRef     socketAccept;
NSMutableArray  *arrayIP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



self.socketAccept = CFSocketCreateWithNative(NULL,
                                  fd, 
                                  kCFSocketDataCallBack,
                                  AcceptDataCallback, 
                                  &context);

[arrayIP    addObject:(id)self.socketAccept];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `CFSocketRef` into a `NSMutableArray` by wrapping it inside a `NSValue`:

```
CFSocketRef socketAccept;
NSMutableArray *arrayIP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
socketAccept = ...
NSValue *val = [NSValue valueWithPointer:socketAccept];
[arrayIP addObject:val];
```

Use `pointerValue` to retrieve the value:

```
CFSocketRef socketAccept = (CFSocketRef) [val pointerValue];
```

Comment: Shouldn't you release val after adding it to arrayIP?

Comment: You don't need to, as val is already auto-released by using the class constructor.

Comment: Of course, the code leaks arrayIP and socketAccept. If they're fixed, then the code is likely to crash because NSValue doesn't retain its pointers. I would just add the CFSocketRef to the array.

Comment: @tc This is just a snippet a code; it is not meant to be perfect. How do you add the CFSocketRef to the array without boxing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Box the `CFSocketRef` into an `NSValue` using the [`valueWithPointer:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-valueWithPointer_) method, then put the `NSValue` into the array.

Comment: Can you take me an example please?

Comment: @zp26 Laurent's answer has an example.